# Collection view cells not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view nested in a table view. The collection view cells are not loading. I am not able to set the collection view delgate and dataSource in the tableViewCell init function because it unwraps as nil, so i created a load function that is called to set it when the cell loads. The issue I have now is that the dataSource/delgate functions are not being called and the table view cell is not loading. My collection view cell for now is just an image, so didn't include that. Also, I have checked that all these outlets are connected correctly, and the table view cell and collection view cell both have reuse identifies set through interface builder. Here is my code:

View Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var libraryTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.libraryTableView.dataSource = self
    self.libraryTableView.delegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LibraryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? LibraryTableViewCell else {
        return LibraryTableViewCell()
    }
    cell.load()
    return cell
}
```

Table View Cell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var carouselLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var carousel: UICollectionView!

func load() {
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    carouselLabel.text = "hello world"

    carousel.delegate = self
    carousel.dataSource = self
    //carousel.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "packCell", for: indexPath) as? PackCollectionViewCell else {
        return PackCollectionViewCell()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If the dequeue method returns nil and you're using xib/storyboard, something's wrong configured, if the cells are added in the xib/storyboard the tableview should load them. Also you should check the height of your cells and make sure the delegate / data source methods are called (it can be a height issue)

Comment: After reading your comment, i decided to delete the table view from the storyboard and start over, and it worked. don't know what the issue was, but its fixed now. Thanks!